# y''+xy'+y=0, y(0)=1, y'(0)=-1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have used laplace transform to get

$Y'(s)-sY'(s)=-1+\frac{1}{s}$

$Y(s)=-e^\frac{s^2}{2}\int e^\frac{-s^2}{2}ds + e^\frac{s^2}{2}\int \frac{ e^\frac{-s^2}{2}}{s}ds +Ce^\frac{s^2}{2}$

what should be done? should I have used a different way. if so what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: (weeks later) I have found an even better approach. The equation becomes much more trivial when fourier transform is used. It is possible to identify, immediately, that the fourier transform of a gaussian is also a gaussian, which gives one of the two solutions, which in return makes it very easy to find the second one.

I wasn't satisfied with y''+xy'+y = (y'+xy )' so I tried really hard to figure out a way.

$$Y(s)=-e^\frac{s^2}{2}\int e^\frac{-s^2}{2}ds + e^\frac{s^2}{2}\int \frac{ e^\frac{-s^2}{2}}{s}ds +Ce^\frac{s^2}{2}$$

I decided I would need this transform to vanish at infinity even though every term blows up. So I decided to pick C such that at s->inf:

$$-e^\frac{s^2}{2}\int e^\frac{-s^2}{2}ds+Ce^\frac{s^2}{2}=0$$

which could be rewritten as (omitting ) constants

$$e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}Erfc(\frac {s} {\sqrt 2})$$

and its inverse laplace transform gives me

$$e^{t-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

Which is one of the solutions. Knowing this solution, makes it very easy to get the second solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Hint:

your D.E is equivalent to ( by taking the integratition for both sides)
$$ y'+yx=C_1$$
by using the boundary condition, we will get
$$C_1=-1$$

Comment: I'm not sure how clear it is from your answer that you exploited the equation $[xy]'=xy'+y$, that is, you used a "mini" integrating factor, essentially.

Comment: I don't understand. It checks out, but am I supposed to look at y''+xy'+y and see that it is the derivative of y'+yx ? Or what if I had y''+(x+1)y'+y ?

Comment: @Ian if you want to check it, take the derivative for the both sides

Comment: wow, how did you see that?(+1)

Comment: @abel It is much like the method of integrating factors for first order linear ODEs, except that the first order part of the equation already has the integrating factor incorporated. The method would not work if the first order part could not be written as $[f(x)y]'$ for some function $f$.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding how I would notice this. Is this something i should try when solving a differential equation? Surely it can't be that solving this equation is only possible by miraculously noticing y''+xy'+y=(y'+xy)'